# Javascript - Backward ( from Leaf to Root ) traversal inside JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object

```
    MyJSON= {
    "name":"ParentName",
    "photo":"images/p.jpg",
    "children":[
      {
      "name":"ChildName",
      "photo":"images/ch.jpg",
      "spouse":[
        {
        "name":"ch-spName",
        "photo":"images/sp.jpg"
        }],
       "children":[
        ...
       ]
      ...
    }]
}
```

I want to traverse forward and backward. 
ie if user selects a child it should show the tree of that particular object. It can go up to the end. From there it should be able to traverse backward also. 
I managed to traverse forward, it works fine. How can I traverse backward?
I am using Javascript for this.

Comment: I think the best approach is to use the JSON data to populate some more sophisticated JavaScript objects. Create an object to represent the topmost person, then create a similar object for each of this person's children. These objects would each contain a link to the parent object.

Comment: To clarify, by "forward and backward" you mean what I would think of as "down" towards children, grandchildren and "up" from children towards parents?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes. I meant Upward and Downward

Answer (score 0):

You can try jquery parseXML , and make the server return a xml instead of json because according to [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1054-jQuery-Demo-Working-With-XML-Documents.htm) , by parsing xml ,

> jData, our jQuery instance object, now contains the XML document object model (#document) which can be traversed using any of jQuery's sweet ass functions (ex. find(), children(), parent(), etc.).